# Регулярное выражение. Исключить из выборки слова в скобках

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строки:

```
Command1 -argument1   -argument2 (param1, -param2)
Command2 -  argument3  (param3) -argument4 (param4, -param2)
Command-3 -argument5  -argument6 (param5) -argument7 (param6, -param7)
```

где Command, argument и param - могут быть любые слова на латинице.

Пытаюсь создать регулярное выражение, чтобы получить только имена аргументов (слова argument1, argument2, argument3 и т.д.). На PHP все работает с такой регуляркой:

```
(?>\/{2}.*?\n|\(.*?\)|(^|\n)\s*?\S+)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<=-) *[a-zA-Z]\w*
```

Пример работы: https://regex101.com/r/mnnzQK/6

Но вот Java такой синтаксис не поддерживает. Помогите адаптировать под Java пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте так : `(argument)[0-9]*`

Comment: Я неточно объяснил, argument, command и param могут быть любые слова. Т.е. оперировать можно только структурой - нужны слова перед которыми стоит дефис, которые не являются первыми в строке и которые не находятся в скобках. Как-то так.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/e0aEad/1 имя в первой группе, если она присутствует в данном проходе.

Comment: Visman, спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью SKIP-FAIL в регулярных выражениях можно отсеять ненужные совпадения. Так как в регулярных выражениях Java нет поддержки этих операторов, можно воспользоваться обычными *захватывающими группами*:

```
/{2}.*\R|\(.*?\)|^\s*\S+|- *([a-zA-Z]\w*)
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/b3C5pC/3)

**Подробности**

- `/{2}.*\R` - 2 символа `/`, 0+ символов, за которыми следует переход на новую строку (`\R`)
- `|` - или
- `\(.*?\)` - подстрока типа `(...)`
- `|` - или
- `^\s*\S+` - начало строки (или позиция после знака перехода на новую строку), 0+ пробельных символов, а затем 1+ знаков, отличных от пробельных символов
- `|` - или
- `- *([a-zA-Z]\w*)` - дефис, 0+ пробелов, а затем *захватываемая группа №1*: ASCII-буква, после которой может быть 0+ букв, цифр и знаков подчёркивания.

[Java-демо](https://ideone.com/xCctzo):

```
String regex = "(?:/{2}.*\\R|\\(.*?\\)|^\\s*\\S+)|- *([a-zA-Z]\\w*)";
String string = "Command1 -argument1   -argument2 (param1, -param2)\n"
             + "Command2 -  argument3  (param3) -argument4 (param4, -param2)\n"
             + "Command-3 -argument5  -argument6 (param5) -argument7 (param6, -param7)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        res.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
System.out.println(res);
```

Результат:

```
[argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5, argument6, argument7]
```